# How to set Yii2 checkbox to checked when attribute name - array?

Tags: php, checkbox, yii2

I'm looking for a simple solution for a "checked" state for the Yii2 ActiveForm checkbox control and I can't find a solution how to set it. I cant find any examples in the documentation.

I've tried to manipulate the rendering code

```
<?php
echo $form->field($model, 'permissions[clients][view_all]')
    ->checkbox([
        'uncheck'=>false,
        'labelOptions' => [
            'style' => 'padding-left:20px;'
        ]
    ])->label('View all');
?>
```

So how set activeChechbox to checked?

Comment: Попробуй перед выводом формы задать значение - `$model->permissions['clients']['view_all'] = 1;`. Что-то типа того...

Comment: Нет, не дает, так как в базе поле permissions = text а никакой не массив

Comment: @ВикторКомягин, чтобы checked сработал, нужно в базе данных хранить числа 1 и 0 (текстом, или цифрой не важно). Либо в вашем случае если у вас массив в виде текста хранится в базе, то перевести текст в массив при передаче к контроллеру (и при сохранении в базу переконвертировать массив в текст)

Comment: Попробовал разные варианты - вроде бы получилось.  Пришлось завести отедльную переменную в модели отличную от того, куда записываю серализованный массив.